# Check if date is in 'Y-m-d' format and is not in future date?

Tags: php, validation, date

I have a form to catch a post input field which will be in date format, i need to check if this post field is in `Y-m-d` format and the date is not in any future date.

```
$dob = $_POST['dob']; 
// 1995-11-03 => Correct format
// 1995-30-12 => Incorrect format
// 2018-09-23 => Incorrect future date
```

Comment: You can never trust a user to input correctly. Swapping places of month and day may still make it look valid but incorrect. I suggest using a calendar picker to select the date, that way you are in controlnof the input

Comment: A calendar picker is javascript, which can be disabled, or the network request could be fudged anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $_POST['dob']);
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

// Check if the date is valid, and that it's in the past
$isValid = checkdate($month, $day, $year) && $timestamp <= time();
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: is it gonna check if the date is not in any future date?

Comment: Updated, hope that helps

Comment: I tried to check if the date is not the future date `mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year) <= time()` but it's not working? the date is 2018-11-11

Comment: It works fine for me - here is an example including some psuedo unit tests to show you: https://eval.in/1000762

Comment: oh sorry my bad